# Laravel, how to call route from javascript function, using Google Map Marker

Tags: javascript, php, marker

I'm trying to create a marker/direction pointer to route on the Google map, but I don't know how to.

I have added several markers with the information window, and within that window, the title should redirect me to a route.

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much! :)

```js
var data = '{!! json_encode($destinos) !!}';

//console.log(data);
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

```js
//THIS IS THE HTML INFO IN THE MARKER
function htmlInfo(name, descrip){
  var text = "";
  text += '<div class="content_maps">' ;
  text += '<a href="{{ route(\'destinos.detalle\', [\'id\' => data.id]) }}" ><h5>'+name+'</h5></a>' ;
  text += '<p>'+descrip+'</p>' ;
  text += '</div>';
  return text;
}
```

Comment: We're going to need a little more info to answer your question. What's in the JSON you're encoding? Where does the htmlInfo function get called and echoed out? I don't believe you can place the route function in a string like that but I might be wrong.

Comment: Jason is to call the table 'destinations' from the database, from the destinations table, I can extract the name, latitude and longitude to add the marker, and in the name is where I want to link a location using a route.